# making area of an html page a link

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am working on a webpage with navigation at the top. I was wondering how to make an area of an html page clickable. That way one could click not just on the text in the navigation bar but a general area around the text in order to navigate from page to page. When I keep trying to do it, it generally messes up the divs I already have on the page.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example or a little more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem propertly:

Try setup `display: block;` for your menu text links, + add them `padding`. Also possible to use `width` and `height`

So active link will be not only the text, but also the area around it.

Answer (score 1):

There are only a small set of HTML elements that you can place inside an `<a>`, and I am guessing none of them is doing the job for you. For example, a div cannot be placed inside an `<a>`.

In that case, you can use javascript or jQuery to listen for a click on a certain defined area, say a div, on the page and respond to it by changing the address (say by changing `window.location.href`). This will have the same effect that you are looking for.

Please note though that usability and design ethics demand that a user of your website knows that a certain area is a link and will take you somewhere else before they click it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by area you mean an entire div? We can use javascript (jQuery) to do this:

```
$("#mydiv").click(function() {
   window.location = 'http://www.google.com'; // redirect here on click
});
<div id="mydiv">
   <!-- this area we can click -->
</div>
```

Comment: Jquery is one way and a simple `<a href="http://www.google.com>Your text </a>`  is another